# SQL Вернуть другую строку, если не найдена первая

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, select

Подскажите как вернуть строку, если не найдена первая.

Например:
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ID = '1' **ИНАЧЕ** SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ID = '2'.

БД postgres

Comment: смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1397680/218971 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164645/218971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выберите обе, и отсортируйте в правильном порядке, взяв только первую строку.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE id IN ('A','B')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
LIMIT 1
```

подразумевая, что ID у вас не просто 1,2, т.к в этом случае можно просто `order by id` сделать